# Unable to append to df while iterating through Try/Except

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through pdfs to extract information from emails. My individual regex statements work when I try them on individual examples, however, when I try to put all the code together in a for loop to iterate over multiple pdfs at once, I am unable to append to my aggregate df (I'm currently just creating an empty df). I need to use the try/except because not all emails have all fields (eg. some do not have the 'Attachments' field). Below is the code I have written so far:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_rows=999
import numpy
from numpy import NaN
from tika import parser

root = r"my_dir"

agg_df = pd.DataFrame()

for directory, subdirectory, files in os.walk(root):
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(directory, file)
        print(file)
        raw = parser.from_file(filepath)
        img = raw['content']
        img = img.replace('\n', '')

        try:
            from_field = re.search(r'From:(.*?)Sent:', img).group(1)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            sent_field = re.search(r'Sent:(.*?)To:', img).group(1)
        except:
            pass
        try:    
            to_field = re.search(r'To:(.*?)Cc:', img).group(1)
        except:
            pass
        try:    
            cc_field = re.search(r'Cc:(.*?)Subject:', img).group(1)
        except:
            pass
        try:   
            subject_field = re.search(r'Subject:(.*?)Attachments:', img).group(1)
        except:
            pass
        try:
            attachments_field = re.search(r'Attachments:(.*?)NOTICE', img).group(1)
        except:
            pass

        img_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['From', 'Sent', 'To', 
                                       'Cc', 'Subject', 'Attachments'])
        img_df['From'] = from_field
        img_df['Sent'] = sent_field
        img_df['To'] = to_field
        img_df['Cc'] = cc_field
        img_df['Subject'] = subject_field
        img_df['Attachments'] = attachments_field

        agg_df = agg_df.append(img_df)
```

Comment: I think if one of your try statements fails then you will pass the previous  emails value for that field to your DataFrame. Because your except statement doesn't do anything so the value of that variable will be unaltered from the previous iteration.

Comment: Along with what @iamchoosinganame stated, I would have it pass in a default string or None value in your except statements instead of just passing. That way you know where the fields don't exist in your final dataframe, and avoid any unexpected results form a blanket `except` statement

Comment: ok i think i got it working! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things:

1. When you don't get a match you shouldn't just pass the exception.
   You should use a default value.
2. Don't append to your dataframe after each time through the loop.
   That is *slow*. Keep everything in a dictionary, and then construct
   the dataframe at the end.

E.g.

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

for directory, _, files in os.walk(root):
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(directory, file)
        print(file)
        raw = parser.from_file(filepath)
        img = raw['content']
        img = img.replace('\n', '')

        from_match = re.search(r'From:(.*?)Sent:', img)
        if not from_match:
            sent_by = None
        else:
            sent_by = from_match.group(1)
        data["from"].append(sent_by)

        to_match = re.search(r'Sent:(.*?)To:', img)
        if not to_match:
            sent_to = None
        else:
            sent_to = to_match.group(1)
        data["to"].append(sent_to)

        # All your other regexes

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Also, if you're doing this for a lot of files you should look into using [compiled expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile).